# How do I initiate button based on status from Firestore database?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to initiate the button to show the current(true/false) status of the item.

In this case, shown as "Taken" if true or "Returned" if false.

So the initial state could be true or false based on the data from Firestore, and with a click on the button, it can be toggled to the other state.

It seems that my button does not take in the current state. What did I done wrong with my code?

```
function App() {
    const [toys, setToys] = useState([]); 
    const toysCollectionRef = collection(db,"toys"); 
    const [newAvailability, setAvailability] = useState([]);

    const toggleStatus = async (toyID, availability) => {
        const userDoc = doc(db,"toys",toyID);
        const newFields = {availability: true}
        await updateDoc(userDoc, newFields);
        window.location.reload(false);
      };

      useEffect(() => {  
        const getToys = async () => {  
          const data = await getDocs(toysCollectionRef); 
          setToys(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id:doc.id }))) 
        };

        getToys();
      }, []);
    
          return (
              <div className="App">
                    <table>
                       <tr><td>Availability</td></tr>
                            {toys.map((toy) => { 
                                
                            return (<tr>
                                        <td>{Boolean(toy.availability).toString()}</td>
                                        <td><button onClick={() => 
                                            {toggleStatus(toy.id, toy.availability)}}> 
                                                       Update Toy Status</button>
                                            {toggleStatus ? "Returned" : "Taken"}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>)  
                                })} 
                    </table>
                </div>
                );         
    } 

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `toggleStatus()` you have hard-coded availability to always be true:

```js
const newFields = {availability: true}
```

You likely want that to be:

```js
const newFields = {availability: availability}
```

Also, once you update your document you are not re-fetching the values from Firestore.

So you either need to:

1. handle that as part of your client update -- by updating the `toys` state variable when you update the data in Firestore, or
2. (much better yet!) use `onSnapshot()` instead of `getDocs()` so that your app is constantly fetching the latest data from the query via "realtime listeners".

If you decide to go with the first approach, you might try:

```js
const toggleStatus = async (toyID, availability) => {
  const userDoc = doc(db,"toys",toyID);
  const newFields = {availability: true}
  await updateDoc(userDoc, newFields);
  setToys(curVal => {
      let newVal = curVal.map(toy => {
        if (toy.id === toyID) {
          return {...toy, availability: availability}
        } else {
          return {...toy}
        }
      });
      return newVal;
    });

  window.location.reload(false);
};
```

where you are updating both the FS document (`updateDoc()`) and the local state variable holding that same data (`setToys()`).

Comment: Yes, i did that too, but it still indicated as False throughout. Hmmm... what could we be missing here? :/

Comment: Answer updating to provide options on how to deal with the changing data going to Firestore.